# Does Captain Tsubasa on PS2 have English version or English patch?

Tags: ps2, captain-tsubasa

Does [Captain Tsubasa on PS2](http://captaintsubasa.wikia.com/wiki/Captain_Tsubasa_%28PS2%29) have an English version or English patch? This game is great but unfortunately I don't know Japanese at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[No](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps2/934171-captain-tsubasa/data). And it looks like there hasn't been any attempts by fans to rewrite the script for the game (at least not that I could find). PS2 games are usually not quite as easy to 'patch' as, say, a PC, NES, or Gameboy game.

It does look like you [aren't the only one](http://www.evo-web.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=34807) who wants to see it though.